# How to deal with a friend mocking my family?

Tags: friends, family, india, parents, friendship

I am 21 years old and have these friends who went to school with me. They were my classmates back then. We were close during our school days, but departed in our own ways once the school was over. We joined different colleges and spent 4 years studying during which none of them kept in touch with me.

After the college got over, I got a call from an unknown number, mocking my family and their profession. I straight away recognized that it was them, because only they knew about my parents and their jobs. Also, I was able to tell because of their distinctive voices. I wrote it off, and casually asked how were they doing. Out of the blue, one of them (It was a conference call) went on to ask whether my X (my dearest family member) was still alive (in a mocking tone).

I went numb and couldn't utter a word. My "friend" kept on mocking asking the same thing. When I told X is fine, he asked why is X still alive, and that X should die. He had never met X so I'm guessing he has nothing against X but just to mock me and sound cool with other friends.

I even tried telling my friend that such an act is totally not cool and that I don't appreciate it, but he asked me to go f**k myself up.

The good news is that I live in a different city but they live in my home city, where my family lives, so whenever I go to my hometown, I might face them.

I feel like I may want to keep in touch with them because they could be just doing it for fun, but I am deeply hurt. I hope they recognize their mistake. How should I tell them so?

Comment: Did the caller(s) confirm in any way that you had correctly identified them? How certain are you that no-one outside your family and former friends knows about what your parents do for a living? And what country are you from (best to add the tag)? Depending on where you're from, the police might be able to intervene if the harassment continues.

Comment: How the other friends reacted to the mocking one? They ignored? Encourage him? Told him it's not nice? - Have you talked to the others about this situation? Maybe they can shed a light on it.

Comment: Is this related to the caste system? I'm no expert in these things, but I would think that could/would be a broadly applicable and popular question.

Comment: Why do you think "just telling them so" would not work? If you don't specify more goals, this is simply a phrasing request, which is off-topic also.

Comment: This is not related to the caste system. They are my same caste. I tried telling them but they only mock me further.